# Regex matching of simple expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to regex and can't figure out how to match the following in C# using `Regex.Matches`

```
left -> right
```

I tried `"(\w) -> (\w)"` but I think I'm way off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not way off, you need:

```
(\w+) -> (\w+)
```

I would recommend [this](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx) guide for learning regex.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that using `Regex.Matches("left -> right", @"(\w+) -> (\w+)");` I'm getting one capture for the whole string, not two separate captures with 'left' and 'right'.

Comment: @Martin, you need to check the match `Groups`. If you want two matches, use just `\w+`, but that will match every word

Comment: *Regex.Matches ( "left -> right", @"(\w+) -> (\w+)" )[0].Groups[1]* matches the left. *Groups[2]* matches the right. Note *Groups[0]* will match the whole string..

Comment: You may find it useful to use named groups. Use the regex **(?<one>\w+) -> (?<two>\w+)** and then you can refer to the group by name : **Groups["one"]** and **Groups["two"]**

Answer (score 2):

```
Match m = Regex.Match("left -> right", @"(\w+) -> (\w+)");

Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);  //left
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2]);  //right
```